# matplotlib.pyplot.scatter() loses color when importing seaborn package?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am working on generating some scatter plot with `matplotlib.pyplot.scatter()` in jupyter notebook, and I found that if I import `seaborn` package, the scatter plot will lose its color.  I am wondering if anyone has a similar issue?

Here is an example code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sb

plt.scatter(range(4),range(4), c=range(4))
```

The output is

[image]

The scatter plot without `seaborn` is:

[image]

Comment: This is related to seaborn setting a color palate where it appears the default color map is grayscale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to fix this is to specify `cmap` option for `plt.scatter()` so that it would not be affected by `seaborn`:

```
ax = plt.scatter(range(4),range(4), c=range(4), cmap='gist_rainbow')
plt.colorbar(ax)
```

The result is:
[image]

There are many options for `cmap` here:

http://matplotlib.org/examples/color/colormaps_reference.html

Answer (score 1):

That seems to be the way it behaves. In seaborn 0.3 the default color scale was changed to greyscale. If you change your code to:

`plt.scatter(range(4),range(4), c=sb.color_palette())`

You will get an image with colors similar to your original. 
See the Seaborn docs on [choosing color palettes](https://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/tutorial/color_palettes.html) for more info.

Comment: Thanks!  How should I convert a list into seaborn colors?  For instance, how should I set colors if I would like to color these data points with list [1,4,2,0] instead of [0,1,2,3]?

Comment: @username123 You could create a list of the colors in the order you want to use and then pass that list into your `c=` keyword. There is likely a way to do it like you are asking, but i'm not sure of how to do it.